# Call to undefined function splice()

Tags: php, arrays, session, splice

I want to unset session array and also remove index of array.

```
$productno = $_GET['productno'];

unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productno]);

$_SESSION['cart'].array_splice(index, $productno);
```

Error : **Fatal error: Call to undefined function splice()**

what is wrong in above code

Comment: This is not JavaScript, in PHP there is no function called splice, and you cannot even call methods on strings. You are probably looking for this function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php

Comment: still wrong....updated answer

Comment: why down vote? anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use : array_splice();

```
array_splice($_SESSION['cart'], $index, $productno);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$productno = $_GET['productno'];

unset($_SESSION['cart'][$productno]);


$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$_SESSION['cart'] = array_splice($cart, $productno);
```